# Mass Email Via Python, Custom Body

Tags: python, email, smtp

New to Python, I'm trying to write a mass-email script (it will be sent via gmail).

Basically I have got it working, however I need to edit each message body separately with a greeting to name of the e-mail recipient. Currently the body is read off a `body.txt` file and I am not sure how to edit it. Example:

`body.txt`

```
Hi <recipient>,

Here is your voucher code.
```

And this is my script, `send_email.py`:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

from_address = "xyz@gmail.com"
file = open("body.txt","rb")
message = MIMEText(file.read())
file.close()
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(from_address, "XXXXX")
server.set_debuglevel(1)
sender = from_address
recipients = ['abc@gmail.com', 'def@gmail.com']
message['Subject'] = "Voucher Code"
message['From'] = sender
message['To'] = ", ".join(recipients)
server.sendmail(sender, recipients, message.as_string())
```

I think most probably I will have to create another list with the names of `recipients` and match them to the email addresses to be sent to, but I'm not sure how to go from there. In fact, I'm not even sure this is the best way- it works though, so I'm pretty happy so far, apart from not being able to edit the body. How do I go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen what you did and I think it's a great start. To edit in the recipients name to the message is really quite simple. You need to format the string. Here's an example:

```
emailBody = "Hello {}, this is my email body. As you can see this program inserts every recipient separately. Hopefully it is helpful. \n"
recipients = ["Ann", "Josh", "Bob", "Marie"]
for recipient in recipients:
    print(emailBody.format(recipient))
```

The main thing is that your emailBody must include symbols {} and then you can use

```
emailBody.format(content)
```

to put something into those brackets.